# How to change android studio indent settings for braces

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to create an array like looks like this for example:

```
String[] arr =
{

};
```

But Android Studio code style settings will only let me do these:

```
String[] arr = {

};
```

or

```
String[] arr =
    {
    };
```

I know that you can tweak these settings in the `Code Style => Java` section, but I can't figure out which one solves my problem. I've spent 30 minutes on it already :<

Answer (score 1):

Under Editor>Code Style>Java>Wrapping and Braces, go to braces placement and set each of the options to Next Line. That will set the opening brace in the next line for class declaration, method declaration and everything else.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that. But the problem is the indentation before the brace (as show in the last example).

Comment: Are you using Next Line Shifted?

Comment: No, I'm not. That adds even more indentation.

Comment: what version of AS are you using?

Comment: I'm using ver 1.5.1 (which seems to be the last one),

Comment: Okay, I'm on 2.1 Preview 5. Let me see if I can find a copy of 1.5.1 to look at.